# monitoredRegions empty even though startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy: is called

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2, core-location

I am developing a iPhone app running on iOS5, and am unable to set up geofences when I call the `startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy:` method on click of a button.

It works fine in the simulator when I print out the regions in `monitoredRegions`, but when running on an actual iPhone 4, the `monitoredRegions` is always empty. Expectedly, the `didEnterRegion:` and `didExitRegion:` methods are not called as well.

Another puzzling fact is that on BOTH the simulator and the iPhone 4 device, the CLLocationManagerDelegate method `didStartMonitoringForRegion:` is never called as well.

Would appreciate some help here, thank you!

EDIT:
this is method that I call on click of a button:

```
-(void) queueGeofence: (CLLocationCoordinate2D)selectedBranch userCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)userCoordinate radius: (CLLocationDegrees)radius {
geofence = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:selectedBranch radius:radius identifier:@"geofence"];

CLLocationAccuracy acc = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;

[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:geofence desiredAccuracy:acc];
[CLLocationManager regionMonitoringEnabled];

NSLog([CLLocationManager regionMonitoringEnabled] ? @"regionMonitoringEnabled:Yes" : @"regionMonitoringEnabled:No");
NSLog([CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable] ? @"regionMonitoringAvailable:Yes" : @"regionMonitoringAvailable:No");

NSLog(@"LOCATIONMANAGER monitored regions: %@", [locationManager monitoredRegions]});
}
```

Region monitoring is both enabled and available, but `monitoredRegions` is still giving me back nothing.

Comment: You will probably get better answers if you post some code so everyone can see what your issue might be. Regions can be a little finicky, but they aren't terribly difficult to get going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in CLLocationManager.h, the comments in the header for `startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy:` state that

> If a region with the same identifier is already being monitored for this application, it 
>   will be removed from monitoring.  This is done asynchronously and may not be immediately reflected in monitoredRegions.

Therefore, you shouldn't necessarily expect that `[locationManager monitoredRegions]` would include your newly added region since it is added asynchronously.

Are you implementing the delegate method for `locationManager:monitoringDidFailForRegion:withError:`?  Maybe that's getting called instead of `locationManager:didStartMonitoringForRegion:`.  Also note that a region with the same identifier as an existing region will get removed, so you might be running into some unexpected problems because you're reusing `"geofence"` as your identifier.

Comment: I have got the code to work but have also discovered what you mentioned: that the region is not immediately reflected. What I did was to use the call the start monitoring earlier and the code worked.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be sure, that your app has a permission to use `LocationManager`. Check it when you alloc your manager.

```
[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
```

I had the same trouble when start app and decline a permission. And after deleting and rebuilding app. I had a flag, that user didn't accept it. Turn it on.

Comment: LocationManager is working as I was able to determine my current location etc. I just dont seem to be able to start monitoring any regions even though I specifically called the method

Answer (score 1):

If you are just going by your NSLog, it probably isn't going to work. [locationManager monitoredRegions] returns an NSSet of CLRegions. They won't display to your log that way. Try this:

```
NSSet *setOfRegions = [locationManager monitoredRegions];
for (CLRegion *region in setOfRegions) {
   NSLog (@"region info: %@", region);
}
```